# Question on swift style extension in dart, is it achievable in dart?

Tags: dart

i am trying to do swift protocol style programming in dart because i think its clean. So the question is:
lets say i have a protocol where i must implement the methods in it, so in the class that i use the delegate, i will always have extension outside of the main class and put the delegate method inside, then next time i can even put the delegate methods in a different file, also it has good readability, for example:

```
// delegate method here
extension mainClass{
    void delegateMethod(){}
}
```

then i try to do this in dart with extension, but there is an error at the home page class because it cannot find the mixin method :

```
class HomePage with delegateOne{
    libraryexample.delegate = this;
}

extension delegateMethod on HomePage {
    String getDescriptionForIndex(int index) {
        // TODO: implement getDescriptionURLForIndex
        return "description";
    }
}

mixin delegateOne {
    String getDescriptionForIndex(int index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are syntactic sugar; they don't actually add a method to instances of the class, and they therefore won't help if you need your class to conform to some interface.

I'm not familiar with "Swift protocol style programming", but typically [in Dart, classes use `implements` to satisfy interfaces](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#implicit-interfaces).  For example:

```dart
abstract class delegateOne {
  String getDescriptionForIndex(int index);
}

class HomePage implements delegateOne {
  @override   
  String getDescriptionForIndex(int index) {
    // TODO: implement getDescriptionURLForIndex
    return "description";
  }
}
```